# JavaScript: How do you store objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function CreateSuit(suit){
  this.suit = suit;
  this.vaule = i;
  this.name = name;
}

var twoClubs = new Card ('clubs', 2, 'two of clubs');
var threeClubs = new Card ('clubs', 3, 'three of clubs');
var fourClubs = new Card ('clubs', 4, 'four of clubs');

var deck = [];
```

How do I put these objects into the deck array? Sorry if this is a dumb question I am having trouble finding an answer.

Comment: `deck.push(twoClubs)`

Comment: `var deck = [twoClubs, threeClubs, fourClubs];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, as mentioned in the comments.

1) Instantiate the array with the objects:

```
var deck = [twoClubs, threeClubs, fourClubs];
```

2) Add the objects onto the array:

```
var deck = [];
deck.push(twoClubs);
deck.push(threeClubs);
deck.push(fourClubs);
```

3) You could even instantiate the array and declare the objects at the same time:

```
var deck = [new Card ('clubs', 2, 'two of clubs'), new Card ('clubs', 3, 'three of clubs'), new Card ('clubs', 4, 'four of clubs')];
```

Technically, this is the most efficient way (caveat: this is browser/implementation dependent).

Comment: “Technically, this is the most efficient way.” According to what metric?

Comment: No citation is needed. By not declaring variables outside of the array, OP will perform less operations and use (a minuscule amount of) less memory.

Comment: Or they could be rewritten to exactly the same thing by whichever engine is running them. (I think that seems likely.)

Comment: I'll argue for the less bytes send in the network request then :P

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.  You can initialize the array with the values present:

```
var deck = [twoClubs, threeClubs, fourClubs]
```

Or you can add them to the array on the fly:

```
var deck = [];
deck.push(twoClubs);
deck.push(threeClubs);
deck.push(fourClubs);
```

Or you can even specify where in the array you want to put them:

```
var deck = [];
deck[2] = threeClubs;
deck[0] = fourClubs;
deck[1] = twoClubs
```

Or you can mix and match any of these:

```
var deck = [threeClubs];
deck[1] = twoClubs;
deck.push(fourClubs);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you all for the help! This give me some good options to play with!

Answer (score 0):

Now once you have added object in array using either of methods mentioned in other answers.

```
var deck = [twoClubs, threeClubs, fourClubs];
```

or

```
var deck = [];
deck.push(twoClubs);
deck.push(threeClubs);
deck.push(fourClubs);
```

you can retrieve and remove **last** object from array by using

```
deck.pop(); // remove and return last object
```

or
you can use indexes to retrieve object from specific location

```
deck[1] // returns threeClubs
```